# Use same function for several elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in jQuery and I'm trying to write some small piece of code, but have problem.

Here is code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first-li").hover(function(){
    $(".p-gallery").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

This code work. I want to use this code on each element from list:

```
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
                <li class="first-li"><a href="images/col1.jpg"><img src="images/col1.jpg" /><p class="p-gallery">Title</p></a></li>
                <li class="first-li"><a href="images/col2.jpg"><img src="images/col2.jpg" /><p class="p-gallery">Title</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/col3.jpg"><img src="images/col3.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/col4.jpg"><img src="images/col4.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/col3.jpg"><img src="images/col3.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/col4.jpg"><img src="images/col4.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/col1.jpg"><img src="images/col1.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't want to use these classes first-li for `<li>`, and p-gallery for `<p>`, just to make possible to each element from list get this jQuery functionality.
I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "cbp-rfgrid > li" ).bind( "hover", function() {
  $("p").slideToggle();
});
});
```

but it doesn't work. :(
Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Are you just looking for `$(this).find('p').slideToggle()` ??

Comment: I have images in list and need to make effect on hover that slide toggle this paragraf Title. That's my task.

Comment: Every image must have paragraph that slideToggle on hover. I didn't wrote here for each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each element in your list looks something like this:

```
<li class="first-li"><a href="images/col1.jpg"><img src="images/col1.jpg" /><p class="p-gallery">Title</p></a></li>
```

The following should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".cbp-rfgrid > li" ).hover(function() {
      $(this).find("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: not trying to take credit for what I didn't say first, but indeed, @FranVerona made an important point in his answer: make sure that you add a dot (`.`) in front of your selector if you're referring to a class, ie. `cbp-rfgrid > li` should be `.cbp-rfgrid > li` instead, but it was just one of the errors.

Comment: Thank you. You save my day!!! :) I tried something with this, but no find() fuction.

Comment: happy I could help... just one more thing: watch what @FranVerona said in his answer: don't confuse yourself with selectors in jquery!

Comment: It was my mistake, I forgot dot. I know that in jQuery you take elements as same as in css.

Comment: It's a common mistake (I forget it from time to time too), but webeno hits directly on the diana :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem could be solved only adding a dot on your JQuery sentence:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".cbp-rfgrid > li" ).bind( "hover", function() {
     $("p").slideToggle();
   });
});
```

Class 'cbp-rfgrid' = $(".cbp-rfgrid")

Tag name  = $("cbp-rfgrid")

You are taking elements with that tags, and they don't exist. I hope it helps you. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for answer but it doesn't work with dot, that wasn't problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that then. It's a common mistake to forget dots on selectors and I supposed that could be that :)